# Convert API binary Data in Python to Paste into XLSX

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I need help converting my api contents into an xlsx

```
print(download.headers)
print(download.content)
```

{'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Content-Length': '990913', 'Content-Type': 'text/csv', 'Expires': '-1', 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=Report.csv', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Date': 'Fri, 22 Jun 2018 19:17:23 GMT'}

the result is a binary string csv deliminated by commas:
,"3/29/2018 12:00:00 AM","3/29/2018 12:00:00 AM","961015","-2500","-2500","100","Contract: 13","0.01","-1","4","-2500","13565197"\

Pasting it into xlsx will just paste the entire content into a single cell. How can I format this and put into xlsx where each attribute is in a single cell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgpIg.png)

the top row is how the data is currently being entered - want it to look like the second row where each attribute has its own column, but I want Python to be able to make the change and paste the data into excel already broken into individual columns.

Thanks

Comment: If you can get a string into a single cell, you are 75% complete already.  If you update your question to indicate how the string should be parse, cell-by-cell, we can assist you.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks - was just getting stumped. Ive added a pic of what I'd want it to look like.

Answer (score 1):

In **B1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(34),"")
```

this removes all the double-quotes.  Then in **A2** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($B1,",",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]

Comment: Im trying to paste the data into excel without having to do that. How can I take the binary data string in python and paste it into an xlsx sheet into columns. Does that make sense?

Comment: @murkcity  It is possible, but it requires more python coding..........not in my skill-set.............sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try Text to Columns with `,` as delimiter.